# SchemaUpdate doesn't work

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate

I made changes to the mapping (added a new table, changed some existing ones), started my app and `SchemaUpdate` didn't do anything and also didn't throw an exception. I checked with pgAdmin and the schema wasn't updated.

```
if (sessionFactory == null) {
    var configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.Configure();
    configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Building).Assembly);

    new SchemaUpdate(configuration).Execute(true, true);
    sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

How can I make `SchemaUpdate` work?

Edit: There are also no exceptions stored in the `SchemaUpdate` Exceptions property.

Edit2: Nhibernate Version v4.0.30319, not using Fluent.

I tried to export the generated SQL, but the `Action` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, SchemaUpdate only does nothing to a table if it exists. So, the only way to update a table using SchemaUpdate is to manually delete it before application startup.